# How can I pause/resume a playing sound that was started with repeatActionForever

Tags: ios, audio, sprite-kit

I have started playing a sound loop in the following way:

```
SKAction *soundAction = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"walking.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:soundAction] withKey:@"walking"];
```

How can I pause/resume it immediately?

Answer (score 0):

For things like background music or sounds you want more control over, apple docs recommend using AVFoundation instead of SKAction-based sounds.

There's a handful of workarounds if you don't want to do that.  You can remove specific actions

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"walking"];
```

but then you'd either have to re-instantiate the initial action, or you could make it an iVar, to re-start it.

The other SpriteKit workaround would be to give it its own non-visual node, and have the node be an iVar or property.  Then run your sound effect action on this node instead of on self, and to pause it, you can just pause the node.

```
node.paused = YES;
```

Comment: I already playing a background music with AVFoundation. The mentioned sound is a running noise for a player. If the palyer stops, the noise should also stop. I tried your first suggestion, [self removeActionForKey:@"walking"]; but it doesn't work

Comment: Where are you starting this action? If it's being called multiple times, that might be the issue. You could put the instantiation inside of an if statement like `if(![self actionForKey:@"walking"];` to ensure it's only happening once.  Are there other actions running on the scene? You could always `[self removeAllActions];`